# Who would be my employer and supervisor if I volunteered somewhere?

Tags: applications

I am filling out a job application. It is asking for my past employment or volunteer experience. One of the things I have to answer is who my supervisor and employer was, but I heard an employer is the person who pays you, and I wasn't payed since I was just volunteering. Would I put the same person for the supervisor and employer? Or would I put N/A for the employer? Or would I put something else?

Comment: Yeah, just leave the employer field empty. It's ok to leave some fields empty on a form.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're overthinking this.

As they asked for volunteer experience, just put the name of the organisation you were volunteering for, and the name of whoever told you (asked you) what to do.